# Script tags stripped when using presto video player in WP Courses single lesson page

Tags: javascript

I am using presto video player for lessons of courses on my website created with the plugin WP Courses. Unfortunately in some pages WP Courses uses ajax and this is maybe causing the javascript script tags of presto video player to be stripped.
You can see this if you go to https://danpishop.com/courses/ and click on any "Start Course" button. The result page does not show the video and the content of the javascript is displayed as text...  **" var player = document.querySelector('presto-player#presto-pl...."** (in "") instead of **var player = document.querySelector('presto-player#presto-pl**.
any suggestion?

Comment: You'll need to ask the plugin's support team for help with this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.